# sudo: docker-compose: command not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run docker-compose using sudo.

I have both docker and docker-compose installed on Ubuntu 16.01.

Due to an error while trying to download compose using curl, I ended up installing it using pip.

Docker version 1.12.0, build 8eab29e
docker-compose version 1.8.0, build 94f7016

Yet, when I try to run docker-compose with sudo I get the following (using sudo with docker is fine)

```
sudo: docker-compose: command not found
```

I suppose there are differing definitions of what 'installed' means. I have been using docker-compose on the same computer that claims it is not installed.

```
$ dpkg -s docker-compose
dpkg-query: package 'docker-compose' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.


$ whereis docker-compose
docker-compose: /home/user/.local/bin/docker-compose

$ pip show --files docker-compose
---
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: docker-compose
Version: 1.8.0
Summary: Multi-container orchestration for Docker
Home-page: https://www.docker.com/
Author: Docker, Inc.
Author-email: UNKNOWN
Installer: pip
License: Apache License 2.0
Location: /home/anton/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: six, jsonschema, enum34, cached-property, websocket-client, docker-py, requests, docopt, dockerpty, PyYAML, texttable
Classifiers:
  Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable
  Environment :: Console
  Intended Audience :: Developers
  License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License
  Programming Language :: Python :: 2
  Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7
  Programming Language :: Python :: 3
  Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4
Files:
  ../../../bin/docker-compose
  compose/GITSHA
  compose/__init__.py
  compose/__init__.pyc
  compose/__main__.py
  compose/__main__.pyc
  compose/bundle.py
  compose/bundle.pyc
  compose/cli/__init__.py
  compose/cli/__init__.pyc
  compose/cli/colors.py
  compose/cli/colors.pyc
  compose/cli/command.py
  compose/cli/command.pyc
  compose/cli/docker_client.py
  compose/cli/docker_client.pyc
  compose/cli/docopt_command.py
  compose/cli/docopt_command.pyc
  compose/cli/errors.py
  compose/cli/errors.pyc
  compose/cli/formatter.py
  compose/cli/formatter.pyc
  compose/cli/log_printer.py
  compose/cli/log_printer.pyc
  compose/cli/main.py
  compose/cli/main.pyc
  compose/cli/signals.py
  compose/cli/signals.pyc
  compose/cli/utils.py
  compose/cli/utils.pyc
  compose/cli/verbose_proxy.py
  compose/cli/verbose_proxy.pyc
  compose/config/__init__.py
  compose/config/__init__.pyc
  compose/config/config.py
  compose/config/config.pyc
  compose/config/config_schema_v1.json
  compose/config/config_schema_v2.0.json
  compose/config/environment.py
  compose/config/environment.pyc
  compose/config/errors.py
  compose/config/errors.pyc
  compose/config/interpolation.py
  compose/config/interpolation.pyc
  compose/config/serialize.py
  compose/config/serialize.pyc
  compose/config/sort_services.py
  compose/config/sort_services.pyc
  compose/config/types.py
  compose/config/types.pyc
  compose/config/validation.py
  compose/config/validation.pyc
  compose/const.py
  compose/const.pyc
  compose/container.py
  compose/container.pyc
  compose/errors.py
  compose/errors.pyc
  compose/network.py
  compose/network.pyc
  compose/parallel.py
  compose/parallel.pyc
  compose/progress_stream.py
  compose/progress_stream.pyc
  compose/project.py
  compose/project.pyc
  compose/service.py
  compose/service.pyc
  compose/state.py
  compose/state.pyc
  compose/utils.py
  compose/utils.pyc
  compose/volume.py
  compose/volume.pyc
  docker_compose-1.8.0.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst
  docker_compose-1.8.0.dist-info/INSTALLER
  docker_compose-1.8.0.dist-info/METADATA
  docker_compose-1.8.0.dist-info/RECORD
  docker_compose-1.8.0.dist-info/WHEEL
  docker_compose-1.8.0.dist-info/entry_points.txt
  docker_compose-1.8.0.dist-info/metadata.json
  docker_compose-1.8.0.dist-info/pbr.json
  docker_compose-1.8.0.dist-info/top_level.txt
Entry-points:
  [console_scripts]
  docker-compose=compose.cli.main:main
```

I have tried the following - but still get the same error:

```
$ chmod +x /home/username/.local/bin/docker-compose
$ chmod +x /home/username/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Comment: *Where* is `docker-compose` installed? Did you install it via a package (in which case, `dpkg -s docker-compose` would verify that), or did you install via some other mechanism?

Comment: The same error, command not found? Did you try to `sudo /home/user/.local/bin/docker-compose ... `?

Comment: As I see, docker-compose is installed in local path which will not be accessible to sudo use `sudo "PATH=$PATH" docker-compose` if /home/user/.local/bin is already in your user path, else use `sudo "PATH=$PATH:/home/user/.local/bin" docker-compose`. (updated answer)

Answer (score 242):

On Ubuntu 16.04

Here's how I fixed this issue: Refer [Docker Compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/)

1. `sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.21.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`
2. `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`

After you do the curl command , it'll put docker-compose into the

> /usr/local/bin

which is not on the `PATH`.
To fix it, create a symbolic link:

3. `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose`

And now if you do: 
`docker-compose --version`

You'll see that docker-compose is now on the `PATH`

Comment: addition of symbolic fixed it

Comment: seems a lot of work, I just ran this command to fix the problem:

> sudo apt install docker-compose

Comment: March 2022 - use this for linux sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.3.4/docker-compose-linux-x86_64 -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

Comment: FrankyHollywood 's solution worked for me

Comment: Simply trying to install Docker Compose was the first thing I tried and it just obliterated my Docker install for some reason, so this was a good solution for me.

Answer (score 35):

The output of `dpkg -s ...` demonstrates that `docker-compose` is not installed from a package.  Without more information from you there are at least two possibilities:

1. docker-compose simply isn't installed at all, and you need to install it.

   The solution here is simple: install `docker-compose`.
2. docker-compose is installed in your `$HOME` directory (or other location not on root's `$PATH`).

   There are several solution in this case.  The easiest is probably to replace:

   ```
   sudo docker-compose ...
   ```

   With:

   ```
   sudo `which docker-compose` ...
   ```

   This will call `sudo` with the full path to `docker-compose`.

   You could alternatively install `docker-compose` into a system-wide directory, such as `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: I want to particularly thank you for including the quick easy solution using the back tic single quotes 'sudo `which docker-compose` . . . ' Works great with the back tic,   fails with anything else...

Answer (score 21):

If you have tried installing via the official docker-compose v1 page, where you need to download the binary using curl:

```
sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.2/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Then do not forget to add executable flag to the binary:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

If docker-compose is installed using python-pip

```
sudo apt-get -y install python-pip
sudo pip install docker-compose
```

try using `pip show --files docker-compose` to see where it is installed.

If docker-compose is installed in user path, then try:

```
sudo "PATH=$PATH" docker-compose
```

As I see from your updated post, docker-compose is installed in user path `/home/user/.local/bin` and if this path is not in your local path `$PATH`, then try:

```
sudo "PATH=$PATH:/home/user/.local/bin" docker-compose
```

Comment: There are multiple ways to install it, pip is one, but it could also be downloaded as a binary.

Comment: I used pip to install compose.

Comment: FYI, it is OK to `pip install docker-compose` without sudo - this will just install for your local user under `$HOME/.local/bin` - afterwards, just update your $PATH in .bashrc/.zshrc/etc to include it: `export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 21):

I have same issue , i solved issue :

Following installs Docker Compose v1:

**step-1 : download docker-compose using following command.**

```
     1. sudo su

     2. sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

**Step-2 : Run command**

```
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

**Step-3 : Check docker-compose version**

```
     docker-compose --version
```

Answer (score 13):

If you are using a more up to date version of docker, you might require `docker compose` instead of `docker-compose`.

For example, I have installed docker on Debian 11.

```
$ docker compose version
Docker Compose version v2.17.2
```

Answer (score 9):

I will leave this here as a possible fix, worked for me at least and might help others. Pretty sure this would be a linux only fix.

I decided to not go with the pip install and go with the github version (option one on the installation guide).

Instead of placing the copied docker-compose directory into `/usr/local/bin/docker-compose` from the curl/github command, I went with `/usr/bin/docker-compose` which is the location of Docker itself and will force the program to run in root. So it works in root and sudo but now won't work without `sudo` so the opposite effect which is what you want to run it as a user anyways.

Comment: As well as moving docker-compose to the other location, it helps to add a symbolic link: `ln -s /usr/bin/docker-compose /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`

Comment: @VinceBowdren I think you meant the other way around: `ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose`

Answer (score 9):

If `docker-compose` is installed for your user but not installed for `root` user and **if you need to run it only once and forget about it afterwords** perform the next actions:

- Find out path to docker-compose:

  ```
    which docker-compose
  ```
- Run the command specifying full path to `docker-compose` from the previous command, eg:

  ```
    sudo /home/your-user/your-path-to-compose/docker-compose up
  ```

Answer (score 5):

Simple, just reinstall the docker-compose. It will fix the issue.

```
sudo apt install docker-compose
```

Answer (score 3):

There are too many pending edits on Stack Overflow, so I'm submitting a new answer that supplements earlier answers.

I propose the answer is syntax: `docker compose` vs `docker-compose` depending on how you have it installed, which is the same proposed answer by ibrahim shazly on Sep 27, 2022 and Gaurav Kumar Verma on Sep 29, 2022.

Here is an explanation. I followed https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-docker-engine to install Docker on Ubuntu 22 LTS. Then, I attempted to run docker compose like so:

```bash
$ docker-compose up -d myserver
Command 'docker-compose' not found, but can be installed with:
...
```

As Gaurav Kumar Verma points out, https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/other/ has a disclaimer:

> Note that Compose standalone uses the `-compose` syntax instead of the current standard syntax `compose`.
> For example type `docker-compose up` when using Compose standalone, instead of `docker compose up`.

Thus, I ran:

```bash
$ docker compose up -d myserver
```

And it ran successfully.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu just run

sudo apt install docker-compose

This worked on Ubuntu 22*

Comment: This will probably work, however, reviving this post so long after where both Ubuntu and docker-compose have gone through multiple iterations is probably not productive. OP have solved the immediate problem and the issue is almost certainly outdated

Comment: Thank you so much. I was facing the same challenge which moved to this issue. When i got the solution, i thouht someone like me might pass through as well and get some assistance.  I really appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

You might be using a deprecated code. Try writing `docker compose` instead of `docker-compose`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.12.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)"  -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

sudo mv /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose

sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, just add your binary path into the PATH. At the end of the bashrc:

```
... 
export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/.local/bin/
```

save the file and run:

```
source .bashrc
```

and the command will work.

Answer (score 0):

**`docker-compose`** is not installed. Please try to install it first from their [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/)

Whenever this type of error occurs please try to verify the installation of the apps by typing **`which command_name`** it will search for the executables and show you the location.

Comment: Answer is outdated as their is longer anything to install. Compose subcommand comes with Docker cli

Answer (score 0):

Had to delete a large log file then restart docker-compose for the space to clear up.
I used a script shell that cron runs once a day:

```
rm /var/log/cron/log_prodTEST.log
cd /opt/test/metrics
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose up --build --force-recreate -d -T
```

Apperntly by using the full path to docker-compose, I could use it inside the corn shell

Answer (score 0):

you might try run the code by using docker compose instead of docker-compose
if it work you might want to check this link her
https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/other/