# How to write bash script for execute PowerShell/Docker command

Tags: bash, powershell, cmd, docker-compose

I want to run `docker-compose ps` or anything else docker command by a bash script.
I have some problem when I try to use bash script in PowerShell/CMD

Example: test.bash

```
#!/bin/bash
docker-compose ps
```

When I try to run:
`test.bash: line 2: docker-compose: command not found`

#### Edit

It's not the problem of `PATH`. I can use `docker-compose` directly in PowerShell/CMD

Comment: The error *probably* means `docker-compose` is not in your `PATH` but you realny should [edit] your question to give us *something* to troubleshoot. Why do you want to run Bash from PowerShell anyway?

Comment: Maybe this can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38775954/sudo-docker-compose-command-not-found/38776946

Comment: Compare the value of the `PATH` variable in PowerShell/CMD and bash. Can you run the docker command with the full path? Can you run the docker command when you append the extension `.exe`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just insert `echo exe` in front of docker-compose on bash file

```
#!/bin/bash
echo exe docker-compose ps
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the commane and the ".exe" extension like:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker-compose.exe ps
```