# Ansible AWX installation failed because of docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, ansible, ansible-awx

I have been trying to install AWX on Redhat 7 but I am getting the following error, I looked around and see some suggestion to uninstall and install the docker-compose, tried whatever I could but nothing worked.

```
    TASK [local_docker : Run migrations in task container] *************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "docker-compose run --rm --service-ports task awx-manage migrate --no-input", "delta": "0:00:00.003315", "end": "2021-02-02 00:25:41.803121", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "start": "2021-02-02 00:25:41.799806", "stderr": "/bin/sh: docker-compose: command not found", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: docker-compose: command not found"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=15   changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=72   rescued=0    ignored=1
```

This is bit strange I try to run the docker-compose -v and worked but when I do sudo docker-compose it doesnt work

```
$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.24.0, build 0aa59064
```

```
$ sudo docker-compose --version
sudo: docker-compose: command not found
```

you see it works without sudo fine, I dont know if this seems to be related to the error I am seeing when installing the awx.

Answer (score 1):

By default pip will install docker-compose in /usr/local/bin/, it appears that Ansible is not including /usr/local/bin/ in the path, I implemented a quick work around by creating a link in /usr/bin/ which fixes the AWX installer error:

```
- name: Create symbolic link for docker-compose
  file:
    src: "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose"
    dest: "/usr/bin/docker-compose"
    state: link
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move ou copy the docker-compose binary do /usr/local/bin, this directory is on the path of normal user and super user.

Comment: it is already in that directory, `ls -l /usr/local/bin/docker-compose*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 16154160 Feb  2 00:21 /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`

Answer (score 0):

I looked at other similar issue in stackoverflow and did the samething for Redhat and it worked :)

Here's how I fixed this issue: Refer Docker Compose documentation

```
sudo curl -L https://github.com/d`ocker/compose/releases/download/1.21.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`

sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

After you do the curl command , it'll put docker-compose into the

```
/usr/local/bin
```

which is not on the PATH. To fix it, create a symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

And now if you do: `docker-compose --version`

You'll see that docker-compose is now on the PATH

Finally run ansible awx installation again, it will work as it worked for me :)

```
$ sudo ansible-playbook -i inventory install.yml
```

Here is the reference for similar issue
[sudo: docker-compose: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38775954/sudo-docker-compose-command-not-found)