# docker-compose on ec2 instance: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I've created an ec2 Amazon Linux instance and tried to build a docker container on it.

I've created a folder called server and put all my source code in it(including DockerFile and docker-compose.yml).

When I run docker-compose up -d, an error occurs.

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/server/db-data/sys'
[4499] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

The db-data serves as a volume for mysql image.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /server

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . . 

EXPOSE 3030

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  test-db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true
      - MYSQL_USER=admin
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=12345
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
    volumes:
      - ./db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
  test-web:
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=local
      #- DEBUG=*
      - PORT=3030
    build: .
    command: >
      ./wait-for-db-redis.sh test-db npm run dev
    volumes:
      - ./:/server
    ports:
      - "3030:3030"
    depends_on:
      - test-db
```

.dockerignore

```
node_modules
npm-debug.log
```

wait-for-db-redis.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
# wait-for-db-redis.sh

set -e

db_host="$1"
shift
cmd="$@"

until nc -z $db_host 3306; do
  >&2 echo "MySQL is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done

>&2 echo "MySQL is up - Executing command"

exec $cmd
```

Comment: Have you tried sudo?

Comment: @AjithGopi: docker-compose: command not found

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59240143/5321660 check this answer out. Locate the docker binary and try with full path.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. find the location of the command using `whereis commandname`.
2. this returns a absolute path to it.
   3)`export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:the/path/you/got`
3. now you can run your command