# How to git clone properly in docker container while using VScode?

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose

My os : Windows

I installed docker and made a container. Inside the [container name]-root, I git cloned. But as I type the command in terminal the error pops up.

[my docker container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShMNg.png)

[terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdLYC.png)

I'm new to using docker and reading a lot of documents explaining it but can't solve the problem yet.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Can you just use the normal VSCode Git integration, without doing anything Docker-specific?

Comment: The error command does not appear consistent with the title. Can [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38775954/sudo-docker-compose-command-not-found) solve your error report?

Answer (score -1):

Often times docker-compose is not installed with docker and must be installed seperatly. Try looking if you have it installed and, if not, install docker-compose and try again.